# Dataset with half weeks at the beginning/end year. How do I merge these in week 1 or 53?

Tags: python

I have a dataset of deaths per week, week 1 is the week with the first Thurday. If there are days of that week in the previous year those are week 53. If there are extra days in January before week 1 those are week 0.
This gives very inconsistent graphs around newyears because the week lengths vary there.
I want week 53 to be merged with week 1 and week 0 with week 53 to get a dataset with no partial weeks.
The dataset looks like this:

```py
            Period                  Deaths
    0       1995 week 0 (1 dag)     394.0
    106     1996 week 53 (2 dagen)  858.0
    108     1997 week 1 (5 dagen)   2268.0
    160     1997 week 53 (3 dagen)  1124.0
    162     1998 week 1 (4 dagen)   1551.0
    214     1998 week 53 (4 dagen)  1732.0
    216     1999 week 0 (3 dagen)   1250.0
    268     1999 week 52 (5 dagen)  2306.0
    270     2000 week 0 (2 dagen)   956.0
```

Is there a good way to solve this?
I can't even wrap my head around it properly since there's also sometimes a week 53 without extra days
I have tried various pandas solutions, but they all don't work, not technically, but principly
Thanks
PS. I've tried this, but is doesnt do exactly what I want:

```py
df['grp'] = (df.Period != df.Period.shift()).cumsum()
out = df.groupby(['grp', 'Period'])['Deaths'].apply(lambda x: \
           ",".join(x)).reset_index()[['Period', 'Deaths']]
```

Comment: Are you using pandas? why don't you just calculate the number of days since a base day and divide them // by 7 to get a kind of week number. In case you have dates and use pandas, this would be a simple task, then you could also normalize the week number afterwards

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have dates, the data is only available per week (including these stupid half weeks)

Comment: So basically it is using isoweeks, but cuts them in half! :/

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up with this solution if anyone needs it:

```py
df['to_first_week']=df.Period.str.contains('dag') & df_clean.Period.str.contains('week 1')
df['to_last_week']=df.Period.str.contains('dag') & df.Period.shift(-1).str.contains('week 0')
df['partial_week']=df.Period.str.contains('dag')
df.loc[df['to_first_week'] == True, 'death_fin'] = df['Deaths'].shift(+1) + df['Deaths'] 
df.loc[df['to_last_week'] == True, 'death_fin'] = df['Deaths'].shift(-1) + df['Deaths'] 
df.loc[df['partial_week'] == False, 'death_fin'] = df['Deaths']
df = df.dropna(subset = ["death_fin"]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I hope it is clear. If week 1 is incomplete, the incomplete week from last year is added to week 1. If week 0 is incomplete, it gets added to the last week from last year